# Design Automation cache life cycle

Tags: autodesk-forge

Our customers would like to know what happens to their data, that is being processed by the Design Automation plug-in. As I understand, the input files are downloaded from the bucket and stored on the Design Automation VM instance while the plug-in runs. But what happens with input and output files when the job is finished? When and how are these resources erased? What happens to the VM itself? Also, could other service/program/user gain access to these files?

Secondly, is there a way to perform RVT->SVF conversion without using cloud services? Does Autodesk provide any desktop tool or API to do it locally?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To the 1st question, in general, the Design Automation Cloud Sandbox will be destroyed as soon as the workitem is done, all the input and output files will be destroyed, that means there should be no other service/app could access these files after the DA workitem is done.

To the 2nd question, No, Rvt-Svf should be done by Model Derivative service, there is no local tool or API to do that from Autodesk at this moment.